# NSTimer Ticking Or Not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

My goal is executing some statements if timer still ticks.

```
while (mainTimer == //is Ticking){
//execute things
}
```

how can i control my NSTimer mainTimer, is or not ticking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask your "`mainTimer`" object if it's valid via the [NSTimer "`isValid`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/isValid).  You can also see when it'll fire next by checking [the "`fireDate`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fireDate).

If you're doing this on a separate "`NSThread`" (e.g. in the background), there's a handy ["`isExecuting`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/isExecuting), too.

(all the blue links up there point to the Apple documentation)

Comment: You'd better be doing this on another thread or you'll have an infinite loop because the answer will never change!

Comment: well yeah!  That's why I made sure to specify "separate".

Answer (score 3):

You would probably use [`isValid`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/isValid) to determine that:

```
BOOL running = [mainTimer isValid];
```

From the documentation:

> YES if the receiver is still capable of firing or NO if the timer has been invalidated and is no longer capable of firing.